# Pass RadioButton selected value to different form

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 radio buttons, when I select one I want to pass that value into a different form so I can use it when a submit is posted. However, I cannot seem to figure out how.

My ultimate goal is to take that selected value of the radio button and pass it into another form so I can use it. I don't want to put the radio buttons inside of that form as well. It wont let me use the environmentName unless I use it in that form upon submission.

View

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical pull-right" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-primary" style="@displayOak">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.environmentName, "OAK")
                    OAK
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary" style="@displayQa">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.environmentName, "QA")
                    QA
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary" style="@displayProd">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.environmentName, "PROD")
                    PROD
                </label>

            </div>

<div style="overflow: auto">
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RenderView)
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProcessId)
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TaskId)
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DeliverableId)
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TaskTypeValue)
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.environmentName)
    }       

    //omitted code
</div>
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult PendingTasks(string submit, PendingTasksModel model)
 {
     EhbProcessType taskProcessTypeCode;
     EhbTaskType taskTypeCode;
     Guid deliverableId;
     Guid userId;
     PendingTaskResult actual;
     string result;
     Guid taskId;
     Guid taskProcessId;
     PendingTaskResult pendingTaskResult;
     InitializeService(Request.Form["environmentName"]); //This is where I want to use the variable

     // omitted code

 }
```

Comment: You are using hidden fields, so on selection of radio button update the value of hidden fields.

Comment: @VinayPratapSingh Is it possible for you to show me an example of how to do that please? Do I need Javascript?

Comment: Here is sample fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/pznL9L1f/
I have used Jquery here.

Comment: Why on earth do you have a form containing only hidden inputs - your sending a whole lot of data to the client and sending it back again all unchanged and just degrading your app and opening yourself to over-posting attacks? A form only posts back the value of its form controls so if the radio buttons are not inside the form tags, then it wont be posted.